# Disqus - Using Single Sign-On exclusively?

Tags: drupal, single-sign-on, disqus

I'm developing a new Drupal site and was hoping to use Disqus for the comments. I have Single Sign-On configured, however I don't see any way of using it exclusively. Meaning, disable sign in with regular Disqus accounts, Facebook, Twitter, and Google, so that only users that have signed up through my site can use it. This is the way IGN.com does it, for obvious reasons, and it seems to work just fine.

I'm trying to create a unified community of users with unique names, and that doesn't really work when anyone can just log in with their Facebook and use whatever name they want. Then there can be a hundred people with duplicate names and the account they're commenting with won't have any ties to my site.

Answer (score 0):

IGN uses a product that is no longer offered by Disqus, and there's no way to restrict the login options to SSO-only.

You might be interested in using AudienceSync, which replaces this. You can read about it and request to use it here: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1104796-single-sign-on-audiencesync